# How to get models related with a model's associated models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models.

Article

```
 class Article < ActiveRecord::Base

   attr_accessible :title, :body, :artist_ids

   has_many :artists, :through => :artist_relationships
   has_many :artist_relationships

 end
```

Artist.rb

```
 class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base

   attr_accessible :title, :body, :article_ids

   has_many :articles, :through => :artist_relationships
   has_many :artist_relationships

 end
```

Now assume I have an `Article` related with two `Artist`(e.g. Michael Jackson, Beatles...)

then each artist has some articles for them.

What I want to do is fetching **all articles** related with an `Article` via its `artists`..

Here is something what I tried (which won't work....)

```
 @article = Article.find(param[:id]) # an Article
 @articles = Article.where(:artist_ids => @article.artist_ids) # get all articles of its related artists
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
@articles = Article.joins(:artist_relationships).where(artist_relationships: { artist_id: @article.artist_ids })
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works fine except that article related two artists appear twice. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't post your code for your ArtistRelationship model, but I assume you completed the has_many_through relationship using:

```
class ArtistRelationship < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :article
 belongs_to :artist
end
```

If you have this set up correctly, then you will be able to take advantage of methods like `@article.artists`or `@artist.articles`.

So you could do something along the lines of:

```
@article = Article.find(params[:id]) #Any given article
@artists = @article.artists #All artists related to the article
@articles = @artists.collect{|artist| artist.articles} #Collection of all articles related to all the artists
```

Comment: I'll check out collect method. Thank you!